# LibreOffice can't open a spreadsheet after lockup

Tags: libreoffice

I have been editing my-file.ods almost daily using LibreOffice. Today it hanged at one point. I had to reboot the laptop. Now the file cannot be edited. When it is opened for editing, a warning is issues: Document file is locked for editing by unknown user.

If I open the file for editing despite the stated hiccup and edit it and then try to save it, I am prompted to save it under another name. But I don't want to change the name.

Answer (score 4):

LibreOffice is creating a "lock file" which looks something like that:

```
.~lock.FileName.xls#
```

If you remove it, you will be able to open your document just fine. To display it, you need to either make Nautilus show hidden files (menu View -> Hidden Files or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>), or open a terminal and type

```
ls -la
```

You should see the lock file. Remove it.

Also in terminal you could find them all with:

```
locate -e .~lock
```